# Farseer accessing a class from OnCollision

Tags: c#, box2d, physics, farseer

I'm using Farseer for physics in a game, and have several key classes: `Planet` and `PlanetProp`. Each planet has a large circular body and a "field". This field is a large sensor around the body. PlanetProps are pulled towards whichever planet's field they are currently in (a struct called PlanetInfo). So I've set up a collision handler in `PlanetProp` which will (whenever it is called) detect whether the fixture it has collided with is a sensor.

I then plan to A) detect if the sensor belongs to a `Planet` and B) Set the `PlanetProp` to be pulled towards the planet

So in other words, is it possible to access a class using a collision callback with a fixture from a body in that class?

EDIT: Does this involve UserData? If I was using C++ I might be able to put a pointer to the class in that, but I'm using c#.

Comment: I don't want to put the whole Planet in it's body's userdata because it has a large image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# there you have "**reference types**" and "**value types**". Reference types are created with the `class` keyword. Value types are created with the `struct` keyword. ([Extended explanation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx).)

A reference (for example a "`Planet myPlanet`" variable if you have `class Planet`) is very similar to a pointer. It takes the same space (32 bits or 64 bits, depending on your architecture) and "points to" (references) an *instance* of a *reference type*. Unlike pointers you can't perform arithmetic on them, and this is so the garbage collector can do its thing and track what objects are still referenced (so they are not collected).

So you are quite safe to set the `UserData` to an instance of the planet object. It will refer to that same object and a copy will not be made.

It's a different story if you have a value type (ie: `struct Planet`). This would get copied when you assign it. (Actually, in this case, because `UserData` is of type `object` and expects a reference type - the framework will "box" your value type by copying it into an immutable reference type.)

Personally I find it helpful - especially when doing game development where you care about memory - to use different syntax highlighting colours for reference types vs value types.

Comment: I had absolutely no idea this was the case. Thank you so much, this is going to make things massively easier.

Comment: References need not be pointers and have the same size as pointers. That Microsoft's CLR implementation uses actual pointers to items in GC-managed tables of objects is an implementation detail. Another implementation might choose to use integer indexes instead and thus references might have different size than pointers, e.g. on LLP64 OSes like Win64.

Comment: @HristoIliev Technically true. But even in that case it's reasonable to conceptualise them as pointers, and treat them as such in practice.